# stuck on do while loop for C++ rock/paper/scissors/lizard/spock game - undeclared identifiers

Tags: c++

I am stuck on something I know should be really simple to fix but I just can't figure it out  I've been Google-ing and gone through my text (Gaddis C++ Intro, Ch. 6) and tried a few things - mostly moving the loop around as I thought I placed it wrong; I've searched through several C++ forums as well and I have found examples where you ask the userj "do you want to continue/play again" but that is not what I am to do, I am to have it automatically restart if there is a tie.  It keeps coming back to the variables not being defined/declared for use within the loop -- except I don't see how they aren't.  I'm using VS 2010.

Here's the code.  I appreciate any help.  I feel kinda stupid for not being able to fix this myself.  This is my first programming class and I'm also taking visual basic at the same time.  It's been interesting.

The debug errors I'm getting are both C2065 "undeclared identifier" for both cpuChoice and userChoice.

```
[code]
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


void outputChoice(int c)
{
  switch(c)
  {
    case 1:
        cout << "Rock";
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Paper";
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Scissors";
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Lizard";
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Spock";
        break;
  }
}

//bool for determining if win or if draw -- loss will be elseif

bool isWin(int userChoice, int cpuChoice)
{
  bool result = 
    (   (userChoice == 1 && cpuChoice == 3) ||
        (userChoice == 1 && cpuChoice == 4) ||
        (userChoice == 2 && cpuChoice == 1) ||
        (userChoice == 2 && cpuChoice == 5) ||
        (userChoice == 3 && cpuChoice == 2) ||
        (userChoice == 3 && cpuChoice == 4));
  return result;
}

bool isDraw(int userChoice, int cpuChoice)
{
  bool result = 
        ( (userChoice == cpuChoice));
  return result;
}

int main()
{
    do{

        srand(time(NULL));

        cout << "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock!" << endl;
        cout << "The rules are the same as traditional Rock Paper Scissors with the additions as follows: Lizard";
        cout << " beats Paper & Spock; Spock defeats Rock & Scissors.\n\n" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        {
            int userChoice;

                cout << "Please choose your move.  Select 1-5: \n\n";
                cout << "1) Rock" << endl;
                cout << "2) Paper" << endl;
                cout << "3) Scissors" << endl;
                cout << "4) Lizard" << endl;
                cout << "5) Spock\n\n" << endl;

                cin >> userChoice;

            if (!(userChoice >= 1 && userChoice <= 5))
            {
                cout << "Please choose 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5!" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                int cpuChoice = rand() % 5 + 1;
                cout << "You chose... ";
                outputChoice(userChoice);
                cout << endl;

                cout << "The computer chose... ";
                outputChoice(cpuChoice);
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;

                cout << "The result is..." << endl;
            }

            if (isWin(userChoice, cpuChoice))
            {
                cout << "You chose wisely!  WINNER!!!!!" << endl;
            }

            else if (isDraw(userChoice, cpuChoice))
            {
                cout << "You chose well, but so did I - TIE!" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "You chose poorly!  You loose!" << endl;
            }

    }
    while (userChoice == cpuChoice);    

    return 0;
}
[/code]
```

Comment: You define `int userChoice` inside a loop - then want to know its value outisde of that loop. Move the declarations to they are in scope when you access them with your `while` statement!

Comment: Just a tip; use an enum to hold the rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock value.

Comment: Re: "solved" in title - normally we don't do that, you click the tick next to the answer that helped you the most. That marks the question as solved in the system. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put "SOLVED" or similar in the title. If some of the answer solved your problem just accept them.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is variable scope. change the first lines inside `main()`:

```
int main()
{
  int userChoice, cpuChoice;
    do {
```

Then inside, instead of declaring these variables, just assign a value:

```
            int cpuChoice = rand() % 5 + 1;
```

should be

```
            cpuChoice = rand() % 5 + 1;
```

And get rid of the other declaration of `userChoice` altogether.

That should do it.

Comment: Or, alternatively, just change the `while` to `while (1);` and add a `break` in the win and lose paths.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - you are right, that would be quite a clean way to solve this. Thanks for the suggestion. I was attempting to explain to OP why he is getting an "undeclared identifier".

Answer (score 0):

You declared these variables int the wrong scope. Move both declarations before the loop

```
int main()
{
    int userChoice;
    int cpuChoice;
    do{

        srand(time(NULL));

        cout << "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock!" << endl;
        cout << "The rules are the same as traditional Rock Paper Scissors with the additions as follows: Lizard";
        cout << " beats Paper & Spock; Spock defeats Rock & Scissors.\n\n" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        {

                cout << "Please choose your move.  Select 1-5: \n\n";
                cout << "1) Rock" << endl;
                cout << "2) Paper" << endl;
                cout << "3) Scissors" << endl;
                cout << "4) Lizard" << endl;
                cout << "5) Spock\n\n" << endl;

                cin >> userChoice;

            if (!(userChoice >= 1 && userChoice <= 5))
            {
                cout << "Please choose 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5!" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cpuChoice = rand() % 5 + 1;
                cout << "You chose... ";
                outputChoice(userChoice);
                cout << endl;

                cout << "The computer chose... ";
                outputChoice(cpuChoice);
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;

                cout << "The result is..." << endl;
            }

            if (isWin(userChoice, cpuChoice))
            {
                cout << "You chose wisely!  WINNER!!!!!" << endl;
            }

            else if (isDraw(userChoice, cpuChoice))
            {
                cout << "You chose well, but so did I - TIE!" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "You chose poorly!  You loose!" << endl;
            }

    }
    while (userChoice == cpuChoice);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very  much!  i just couldn't see it.  works great now.